# Number of items to show in Javascript

Tags: sharepoint, content-query-web-part

I'm using Content Search Web Part on SP 2013, I'm trying to get the value for Number of items to show option in Javascript from the ctx object. I have tried ctx.ListData.ResultTables[0].RowCount but seems like this value is for the count on the current page only, not the configured in the 'Number of items to show' option within web part configuration.

[Number of items to show value in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEZmu.jpg)

In addition, do you know where can I find more information on how to debug the ctx object or the properties or methods it uses. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use JSOM to achieve it. The following code for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveWPProperties, "sp.js");
function retrieveWPProperties(){
    var pageurl=_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath; //current page
    var currentCtx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var pageFile = currentCtx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageurl);
    var webPartManager = pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    var webPartDefs = webPartManager.get_webParts();
    currentCtx.load(webPartDefs, 'Include(WebPart.Properties)');
    currentCtx.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        if (webPartDefs.get_count()) {
            for (var i = 0; i < webPartDefs.get_count() ; i++) {
                var webPartDef = webPartDefs.getItemAtIndex(i);
                var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();
                var properties = webPart.get_properties();              
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(properties.get_fieldValues())); //print all properties
                if(properties.get_fieldValues().Title=="Content Search"){
                    var resultsPerPage=properties.get_fieldValues().ResultsPerPage;
                    alert(resultsPerPage);
                }
             }
        }
        else {
            console.log("No web parts found.");
        }
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
}
</script>
```

[image]